# Placing a circle in a point cloud

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

I need to place a circle with fixed radius in a cloud of points. The circle also must lay in a polygon (the points are also in that polygon) This circle has to contain as many points as possible. Are there some algorithms for this task? I need the best solution for every possible input.  I seek for solutions in python or just algorithms. Although this is a forum for theoretical computer science, I would be happy with a few lines of python or a detailed algorithm.

Comment: https://russelldash332.github.io/CS2030/Labs/Lab1/Lab1.html